# Google App Engine - Multiple Domains

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine allows using Google Authentication and restricting it to a specific Google Organisation domain by setting to 'Google Apps Domain' in the control panel like so:

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvRzF.png)

I am wondering if there is any way of having multiple domains here? Tried comma separated but not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that only works for a single domain.  You'll need to use a more general OAuth2 implementation (e.g., Authomatic) and check the email address of people who login to make sure it matches an allowed domain.